# Pushing a repo on a Gitolite server to Gitolite while also being able to push and pull from a client

Tags: php, ssh, gitolite

I have a Gitolite server which I push my website source code to.  The server then clones the repo into the websites folder using a hook.  I would like to be able to change files in a PHP script in my website then have the PHP script automatically add, commit, and push these changed files back to the Gitolite server.

So far, I've managed to add and commit the files, but I cannot push them.  If I try to push to the local reference to the repository, I am told it doesn't appear to be a repo (a file permissions problem I think as it worked with sudo), and if I try to push via SSH, I cannot specify a private key as I'm running this under the _www user in Lion Server.  Is it possible to push locally to a local Gitolite repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with pushing to Gitolite is to make sure Gitolite can get your id, in order to use this id with its internal authorization config file.
Using ssh is a good way to do that (since the name of the public key registered in Gitolite will be used as your id name)

So:

- you need to make sure `_www` user is authorized to push to your repo
- you need to have a public/private key under `~_www/.ssh` to be used by your push
- you need to add the public key of `_www` user to gitolite keys.

---

The [OP enovav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618502/enovav) comments that:

- On Lion Server, the `_www` user does not have a home folder.
- PHP looks for SSH keys in `/Library/WebServer`.
- It is not possible by default to log in to the `_www` user, however [this thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/99605/login-as-www-user) explains how. (`chsh -u Admin _www` to change the shell from /bin/false).
- The steps can then be followed as above.

Comment: On Lion Server, the _www user does not have a home folder.  I examined the PHP logs and found that it was actually looking for SSH keys in `/Library/WebServer`.  Next step: creating the SSH keys.  I tried to become the `_www` user in the shell by typing `sudo -i -u _www`.  However, this returned nothing immediately and no messages were printed.  After some research, I found [this thread](http://ask.metafilter.com/99605/login-as-www-user), which explains how to log in to the `_www` user in Mac OS X.  I changed the shell using the command `chsh -u Admin _www` and followed the procedure above.

Comment: @enovav Thank you for this feedback. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.